# Mist on Ganache asks for a password on creating transaction

Tags: mist, ganache

I cannot send funds to another my account with Mist, it asks for password. I'm using Ganache testnet, and didn't created any password in it.

I tried to use `ganache-cli -d -u "0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1"` (where -d as I understand is to preserve test accounts, and -u to unlock one of them), send to funds to another new account from 0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1, but it still asks for a password. How to fix it?

Comment: When you claimed your account (the one you are sending the transaction from), you provided a password, I believe it must be this one.

Comment: @Andromelus at starting Ganache already creates 10 accounts, and doesn't ask about password :(

Comment: What if you provide an empty sstring?

Comment: I tried, doesn't work. I'm currently discovering geth with local testnet as alternative